# A function that prints a certain number of a character

Tags: python

Define a function generateNChars(a_nNum, a_Char) that takes an integer a_nNum and a
character a_Char and returns a string, a_nNum characters long

```
def generateNChars(a_nNum, a_Char):
 for i in range (0, a_nNum):
  print(a_Char, end = "")

nNum = int(input("Entyer a number: "))
strChar = input("Enter a character: "))
result = generateNChars(nNum, strChar)
print(result)
```

I got "None" after printing this code. How can I fix this??

Comment: You already have an answer to your question, but as a side node, you might want to make your code more readable and conform to the generally accepted code-style guidelines for Python by using 4-space indentation and naming your variables and functions with the so called `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `return` keyword to return the value. When you don't use a `return` keyword, it returns `None` by default. Therefore when you print the function, you receive `None`. Also, keep in mind that a loop ends when `return` is used. So, instead of using a `for` loop, you  can multiply, which will return the string repeated `n` number of times.

```
def generateNChars(a_nNum, a_Char):
 return a_Char*a_nNum

nNum = int(input("Entyer a number: "))
strChar = input("Enter a character: "))
result = generateNChars(nNum, strChar)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the string from the function. Now, the returned string gets assigned to the `result` variable and you can print it.

```
def generateNChars(a_nNum, a_Char):
    temp = ""
    for i in range (0, a_nNum):
        temp+=a_Char
    return temp

nNum = int(input("Entyer a number: "))
strChar = input("Enter a character: "))
result = generateNChars(nNum, strChar)
print(result)
```